# Are there alternate flash modules for the Lytro Illum 40 megaray camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash, lytro

I own the Lytro Illum 40 megaray light field optic camera and  I wanted to add a flash module to it. I was wondering if you have any suggestions as to what are the possible alternate lash modules to install other than the one made for it. Here is the shoe:

[image]

Comment: Do you need TTL? (See: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722)

Comment: Yes if its works good i will go for it could you specify the ttl model and product name

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any other TTL option available to you other than finding the for-Lytro version of the Viltrox JY680 TTL, the JY680L, given that unusual pin/contact layout. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, that flash has been discontinued, so you'll have to look for a used one. Your only options are going to be manual-only or flashes made for other brands of cameras which will only be able to be used in M mode without HSS, because the non-sync pin/contact won't exist or match, so the only thing your camera can do is to tell the flash to fire.

See also: [Is flash brand X compatible with camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100131)