# Canon EOS 4000D Hot Shoe for Sync (with Studio Flashes)

Tags: canon, hotshoe

The external Flash is not showing up in the configuration Menu when using Pixel TF-321 hot shoe. Is this the wrong adapter for that camera, as there is no X connection?
I want to trigger a studio flash via sync connection. Can you recommend me a working hot shoe? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: related: [What speedlites can work with the Canon non-standard hotshoe found on their low-end camera models](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109122)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution - [Godox XPRO-C](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07J6JB17K/).
70 bucks and I'm able to use the sync! Works with 2000D and 4000D!

Comment: Glad you found something that works for you, even if your solution is not exactly what the question, as written, asked for.

Comment: Well it's a working hot shoe "adapter" that runs without the middle / X contact. Not even Canon is providing anything like this. I even opened a ticket with them looking for a product

Comment: I guess so, if you consider a 'hot shoe' and a 'hot shoe adapter' to be the same thing.

Comment: Other cheaper, Canon E-TTL compatible triggers, such as a YN622-C, might also work.

Comment: Just FYI, on April 26, 2019, Godox issued firmware updates for the XPro-C, X1T-C, and V860II-C for EOS R, 2000D, and 4000D compatibility.

Comment: I did a shooting yesterday and I had problems with the studio flash because didn't sync, Can I use studio flashes with this without any problem?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, your canon EOS 4000D is a very stripped down entry level camera.

Looking at your photo of the hotshoe, I now realize that Canon has removed or eliminated the center hotshoe contact. This is the contact you need to make the sync connection with your Pixel TF-321.

The 4000D will only work with Canon brand ETTL flash units and also ***some*** 3rd party ETTL flash units.

There is no way that I can think of to make your camera sync with an external studio flash.

Any other Canon camera would have had this contact. I find this very troubling and I can't really see how this can be seen as a cost saving measure.

EDIT: There are just 3 Canon cameras affected so far. They go by various names depending on where they are sold: 1500D/2000D/Rebel T7/Kiss X90, 3000D/4000D/Rebel T100 and the new 250D/Rebel SL3/Kiss X10

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I added my studio light. It doesn't work with the TF-321. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just measured all of the connections. On the TF-321 the inner of the PC connection is not connected to any of the pins on the top or bottom. Could it be that the adapter is just broken?

Comment: @Sto I have just edited my original answer. Canon has removed the center contact from the 4000D hotshoe and any normal hotshoe adapter will not be able to sync with the camera.

Comment: I don't mind soldering anything anywhere, but I need that triggered :/ Looking really forward to a solution. This is supposed to be locked in a photo booth. Thanks!

Comment: @Sto The simplest solution in this case is to go with a camera that has a hot shoe the meets the ISO standard.

Comment: Gah. Looks like [they crippled the 2000D the same way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_2000D).

Comment: It looks like there are just 2 cameras affected so far. They go by various names depending on where they are sold: 1500D/2000D/T7 and 3000D/4000D.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Canon has removed the ability to manually trigger a non E-TTL flash with the 4000D by removing the center pin of the camera's hot shoe.¹

> This is supposed to be locked in a photo booth.

If you are bound and determined to use the EOS 4000D, with it's non-ISO compliant crippled hot shoe (SHAME, SHAME, SHAME, on you, Canon!), then you might try reflecting the output from the camera's built-in flash to the optical sensor in the strobe with the strobe set to 'Photosensor' triggering mode. Set the camera's built-in flash to manual flash power. Turn off red-eye reduction plus anything else that causes a 'pre-flash'. Since the camera is mounted inside your photo booth, it should be fairly easy to block the camera's flash from directly illuminating the posing area while bouncing the light from it inside the 'behind the wall' area to trigger the strobe.

<sub>¹ Which, in this case, should probably be called the 'somewhat lukewarm shoe'.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a good solution, I will tape a light sensor to the built in flash, that goes to a sync cable. I hope I can adjust the trigger timing too, would be perfect 

Answer (score 2):

Bought Godox X1T-C and it worked very well for my Canon 3000d. Don't forget to update to latest firmware released 5  May, 2019. Stock version might not work.

Comment: @Viv - how is this not an answer to the question?  OP asks for product that goes in hotshoe and can provide sync.  Answer suggests product that can go in hot shoe and provide sync.  It may be possible the answer is wrong, but that doesn't mean it isn't an answer.

Comment: This seems to be just a "me too" to [Sto's answer](/a/103933/56348).

Answer (score 1):

I have Canon 2000D and learned the hard way that my camera is crippled. Thankfully Godox X1T-C with firmware upgrade v26 bypasses the issue with lack of central pin. So if you want to add remote flash trigger in your toolbox than get Godox XPro or X1T-C trigger.
Just be aware that Godox XPro and X1T-C are compatible only with Godox X system. To trigger my Neewer speedlites I had to get Godox X1R-C as well. One was enough as I'm setting my other speedlites on optical trigger. So being able to wirelessly trigger one speedlite works good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my solution for the incompatible manual flash on canon new hot shoe mounting layout that seen on canon 4000d/1500d/etc.

First I bought a off ttl cord model: OC-E3 TTL and I short circuit the four wire into the x-sync contact and the camera recognize it as a manual flash and now I can use the Manual Flash

Comment: Please post the information you have in this answer rather than asking people to e-mail you - thanks!