# My Camera responds slowly to my external Flash. How can I synchronize my Flash light response with my Canon 4000D?

Tags: canon, nikon, off-camera-flash, event-photography

I bought a speedlight for my 4000D Canon camera. A "Digitalmart" Canon flash to be precised. Fortunately, they work hand in hand, both devices interact with each other. The camera reads that a flash is connected to it and the flash also reads the info on the camera.

The problem i'm facing is that, the Flash responds to the camera shutter, but the image is still dark. In the sense that the camera doesnt read the flash ligh fast enough. So when the flash comes on, the camera does not respond quickly to the light or the camera responds too quickly before the light even comes on. Either way, it brings out dark images. What then could i fix? Could it be a setting? I'm having issues uploading Images, so i'd just write out my on-camera flash settings.

External Flash-Enabled
Flash Mode - E-TLL II
Shutter Sync - First Curtain
FEB - 2
Flash exp. Com - +2
E TLL II meter - Evaluate
Zoom - 24mm

External Flash settings
E TLL 
F5.6
24mm.

Heard its possible to edit questions. If anyone gets my point, please do so to make ammendments in my question. 
I have an induction to cover by Wednesday and I didnt expect this to happen now. Your answers and opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What’s your shutter speed, aperture, and iso set to?

Comment: @Hueco its 8pm over here. Shutter speed is at 1/100 Aperture at 5.0, and ISO at 1600

Comment: Are you in manual mode or is that what the camera picked in a auto or semi auto mode? Why is this tagged `Nikon`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue of Canon and Canon flashes.  That being said, you have your camera set to ETTL II settings and your flash to ETTL settings.  Unless basic ETTL is already exchanging enough information that the camera can adjust to this mismatch, this could be the cause of your problem.  I think that ETTL is one of the earliest protocols working with digital cameras so it might not be all that smart.

My guess is that your estimate is the wrong way round: likely the camera fires the pre-flash for measuring exposure and then fires the main flash before the flash gun is ready for it, consequently ignoring it.

For most digital forms of TTL, there will be two discernible flashes.  Even when pre-flash and main flash are very tight so that you cannot see them, the flash noise will sound "wetter" than a single flash.  If you hear a single dry pop, it's likely only the pre-flash.

Maybe ETTL II has a shorter minimum duration between pre-flash and main flash, and your flash just cannot cope.  Try whether you can use a different flash protocol on the camera, like straight ETTL.

Answer (score 0):

The Canon 4000D has a non-standard hotshoe which causes compatibility issues with non-Canon flash units. More info here: [What speedlites work with Canon 4000D](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109122/what-speedlites-can-work-with-the-canon-eos-4000ds-non-standard-hotshoe)

Comment: I understood this already, thats why I bought an EX-series.

Comment: “Digitalmart” doesn’t sound like it is a Canon brand flash. Which model flash did you buy?

Answer (score 0):

Evening guys. I lost the job some few minutes ago. Lol.
I lost it to my twin sister. She uses a Nikon and she'd be covering the event on Wednesday. 
I appreciate your opinions and answers. I guess the fault came from the speedlight itself, because the manual mode isnt working either. Its a Canon flash, an EX-series and I really can't comprehend what could have gone wrong.

I'd go for an exchange by monday and make sure all modes are working perfectly, or better still top cash and buy a better one.

Thank you all.