# I bought a yn560 Iv speed light for my canon 2000d but its not working with the camera

Tags: hotshoe-flash

My canon 2000d not firing the yn560 iv speed light

Answer (score 0):

For [some awful reason](https://petapixel.com/2019/05/03/canon-made-its-new-entry-level-dslrs-incompatible-with-3rd-party-flashes/), Canon has removed the standard central pin from the hotshoe on its entry level models. This means that you can't use generic, manual flashes with these models, unfortunately.

See [What speedlites can work with the Canon EOS 4000D's non-standard hotshoe?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109122/what-speedlites-can-work-with-the-canon-eos) for flash models which should work.