# Hotshoe flash options for a canon 4000d

Tags: hotshoe-flash

I have the canon 4000d, wonder what flash would be available for it. In the hotshoe? It has a built in flash but it does not automatically pop up.

Comment: Is the built-in flash actually known to be broken? The 4000D has no automatic flash release, you must raise it manually with your fingers when in a creative mode (see page 103 of the English manual)

Comment: If you actually want an external flash for other reasons, can you read [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109122/what-speedlites-can-work-with-the-canon-non-standard-hotshoe-found-on-their-low) and see if that answers your query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What speedlites can work with the Canon non-standard hotshoe found on their low-end camera models?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109122/what-speedlites-can-work-with-the-canon-non-standard-hotshoe-found-on-their-low)