# How do I get a YN560 III flash to work on a canon 4000d camera

Tags: manual-flash

How do I get the Yongnuo YN560 III flash to work with a canon eos 4000d camera?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canon EOS 4000D Hot Shoe for Sync (with Studio Flashes)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/canon-eos-4000d-hot-shoe-for-sync-with-studio-flashes) The specific flash is different, but the issue caused by the lack of an ISO compliant center pin on the 4000D hot shoe and possible solutions are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The EOS 4000 lacks the center contact in the hotshoe. This makes it incompatible with a simple manual flash like the YN560.

Only Canon flashes, (and some 3rd party ETTL flashes) will work without the center contact.

It would be possible to use the YN560 off camera if you use some kind of compatible trigger/receiver combination.