# Why does my pictures becomes darker while using external flash ?

Tags: flash

Camera is Canon EOS 250d 
Flash is YN565EXIII 
Whenever i use this external flash with my camera the image becomes darker 
I am newbie in this photography world so all the thing is set in default 
Just incase if required ( mistakenly i rolled the slider unknowingly which is near the eye lens or eye view )
I dont know how to fix it or we need to change some setting for that pleaee help me

Comment: What exposure mode (M, Av, Tv, P) are you using? What shutter speed, aperture and ISO are you using? Can you post an example picture? I would recommend going for M if using flash photography to determine the exposure for background manually, and then either using E-TTL II automatic flash or adjusting even the flash manually, too. Please note the flash can only light up a foreground, not the background, if the background is far away.

Comment: The slider near the eyepiece is probably the diopter slider. Adjust it for your eyesight.

Comment: Does the flash fire at all?

Answer (score 5):

The Canon EOS Rebel SL3/250D does not have an ISO compliant hot shoe. It's missing the center pin needed to trigger "manual only" flashes. Canon recently started doing this with their lower end entry level cameras.

The Yongnuo YN565EX III is Canon E-TTL capable. But it may not be able to cope with a Canon camera that has the center pin missing on the hot shoe. Many third party E-TTL capable flashes and triggers require a firmware update to work with the Rebel SL3/250D, Rebel T7/1500D/2000D, and Rebel T100/300D/4000D.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the likely problem was that the flash was not firing at all! I thought if the flash didn't fire, it should have been explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @juhist Maybe not. The YN565EX III is supposed to be E-TTL compatible, assuming he's got the Canon version. Updating answer.

Answer (score 4):

The YN-565EX III requires [a firmware update](https://www.yongnuorumors.com/firmware/) to be compatible with the hotshoe of the 250D/SL3, and to fire when the camera tells it to.  Newer entry-level Canon dSLR bodies [have had the sync contact removed from the hotshoe](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/canon-eos-4000d-hot-shoe-for-sync-with-studio-flashes/103689#103689), which can create incompatibility issues with non-Canon speedlights.