# Are there any 3rd-party TTL Leica flash options?

Tags: flash, compatibility, ttl, leica

For Leica TTL flash, are there any third-party options?  I can't find any, so I'm assuming not.  It seems if you own Leica gear and want TTL, you use Leica flashes and nothing else.  Does anyone know anything different?

(Obviously, for manual flash – especially if using a PC port – there are plenty of options available. I'm just talking TTL here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My conclusion as well: you can only get M-TTL with Leica-branded OEM flash gear on a Leica camera. I haven't run across any 3rd-party options. It's possible that Leica-branded Panasonic cameras could use four-thirds flash gear for TTL, but for most Leica cameras (M, X, T or SL), the flash hotshoe is incompatible. [Yeah, Leica and Panasonic share the L-mount for lenses, but not a hotshoe].

And even though Leica's own flashes appear to be made by Nissin (e.g., a Leica SF60 looks *a lot* like an i60A; ditto a SF40 and a Nissin i40, and the SF C1 transmitter is a dead ringer for Nissin's Air 10s), Nissin themselves do not offer "for-Leica" M-TTL versions of that gear at Nissin prices. This was the same deal Leica had with Metz when Metz was making their flashes.

See also:

- [Is flash brand X compatible with camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100131)
- [This comment on l-camera-forum.com](https://www.l-camera-forum.com/topic/268005-nissin-i40-for-leica/#comment-3180614)

**July 2022 update**

There are now two announced TTL options for Leica in terms of flash radio transmitters. Profoto is releasing [a Leica version of the Connect Pro](https://profoto.com/us/news-room/connect-pro-leica) and Godox is releasing [the XproIIL](http://www.godox.com/product-a/XProIIL.html). Neither one is available yet from retailers, but are both on pre-order at B&H at the time of this writing.

But in the case of Godox (at least; may be the same for Profoto) the *lights* will also probably require a firmware update to be fully TTL compatible with the Leica transmitter, since this is how all new system support has been added in the past, and those firmware updates haven't yet arrived. And there are no announcements yet for on-camera flash TTL options.

Comment: The only cross-compatibility on offer seems to be the ability to use Nikon off-camera TTL cables — see https://www.kenrockwell.com/leica/sf-24d.htm § "Other Brands".

Comment: @mooie, as long as the pin/contact placement is identical, a passthrough TTL cable will work. I use a Canon TTL cable in the same way to get TTL/HSS with an Olympus FL50 and my Panasonic GX7. Would also work for Fuij.

Answer (score 2):

Profoto Connect Pro now comes in a Leica version