# Canon flash plus Canon trigger on Nikon body will it work?

Tags: canon, nikon, body

I was Canon user before but now I bought Nikon body . I have a third party flash along with dedicated Canon trigger and receiver and I want to use that flash remotely with those trigger can sync cable will solve my problem?

Comment: If you want full TTL support likely not. Basic "manual" us is perhaps possible, but why don't you try?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to work for manual-only triggering, since both Canon and Nikon ([mostly](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/)) follow ISO standards for their flash feet and hotshoes, but all other features, aside from sync (firing the flash) are not going to work, because they are communicated on the pins/contacts on Canon where Nikon doesn't have anything.

If you are using a manual-only transmitter that can control the power of the flash via a built-in receiver (e.g., YN-600EX-RT and YN-E3-RT or YN-560IV and YN-560-TX), then you may still have remote power control.

But if you want TTL, FP/HSS, etc. you will need iTTL-compatible (for-Nikon) triggers.

See also:

- [Can a Nikon/Canon flash be used on the other brand of camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4550/)
- [Are Yongnuo flashes interchangeable between dslr's or are they brand specific?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/)

Comment: I tried this years ago with my Yongnou 622TX and 622C on a Nikon and it worked fine.

Comment: @Robin, yeah, I did the same with a 622C-TX on my Panasonic GX7. Worked for sync and M power control, but not TTL/HSS/2nd curtain. Can't remember if zoom worked or not, but I think not. I'd heard of the ST-E3-RT and 600EX-RT gear working similarly.